# Simple Pointer of C++ and cin char array

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char *YourName = new char[10];
    cout << "Enter your name:";
    cin >> YourName;
    cout << "\nHere is what your entered:" << YourName;
    return 0;
}
```

Why will this allow more than 10 chars (other than spaces) to be stored? Is this because I am creating a pointer that simply points to the array of chars?

Comment: It's because *undefined behavior* sometimes means working just fine. You can't predict it. If the program were longer or more complex you might see more drastic consequences.

Comment: Why not use std:string?

Answer (score 3):

Undefined behaviour means *exactly* that. Undefined.

And sometimes undefined means it works as you expect it to, even when your expectations are wrong and despite you violating the contract with your language :-)

For *specifics,* most memory allocation routines will work on a certain "resolution" such as 16 bytes (for efficiency), meaning that requests will be rounded up to the next multiple of that value. You may find that you can populate your 10-byte buffer with anything up to 16 bytes before it starts falling in a heap.

That doesn't make it okay to *use* that extra space, it just explains why it may work sometimes.

Comment: I always tend to mention __Schrödinger's cat_, or _interior black hole_  scenarios, to elaborate on _undefined behavior_ ;-) ...

Answer (score 1):

In a larger and more complicated program the extra characters will stomp on adjacent variables in memory. A large enough number of extra characters will eventually trip operating system protection because it can access memory that has not been allocated.

A pointer just points. It has no properties that know the length of what it is supposed to be pointing at.

Answer (score 1):

Thats why always use to `std::cin.getline(YourName,10)` so characters after 10 will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The extractor for `char*` doesn't know what the size of the array is, so it can't stop extracting after 10 characters unless you explicitly tell it to. This is dangerous because it allows you to enter more characters than was allotted to the array. This causes Undefined Behavior.

This is why it's recommended that you use `std::string` instead of C-style arrays because the size of its internal buffer can increase as you add more characters.